# NodeJS : Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)

Tags: node.js, econnreset

Using Polling like below to check if the content of the file is changed then, other two functions are called

> ```
> var poll_max_date=AsyncPolling(function (end,err) {   if(err)   {
>        console.error(err);   }   var stmp_node_id=fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'node_id'),"utf8"); 
>    console.log("--------loaded node : "+stmp_node_id);  
>    if(druid_stmp_node_id!=stmp_node_id)   {
>          // MAX DATA CUT-OFF DRUID QUERY
>          druid_exe.max_date_query_fire();
>
>          // // DRUID QUERY FOR GLOBAL DATA
>          druid_exe.global_druid_query_fire();
>
>          druid_stmp_node_id=stmp_node_id;   }
>
>      end(); }, 1800000).run();//30 mins
> ```

Its working fine for sometime, but then getting below error like after 4 - 5hours :

> events.js:167
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)

tried using fs.watch to monitor the changes in the file instead of polling like below :

> let md5Previous = null; let fsWait = false;
>
> fs.watch(dataSourceLogFile, (event, filename) => {   if (filename) {
>
> ```
> if (fsWait) return;
> fsWait = setTimeout(() => {
>   fsWait = false;
> }, 1000);
>
> const md5Current = md5(fs.readFileSync(dataSourceLogFile));
> if (md5Current === md5Previous) {
>   return;
> }
>
> md5Previous = md5Current;
>
> console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
>
> // MAX DATA CUT-OFF DRUID QUERY
> druid_exe.max_date_query_fire();
> // DRUID QUERY FOR GLOBAL DATA
> druid_exe.global_druid_query_fire();   } });
> ```

Its is also working fine for sometime, but then getting same error like after 4 - 5hours :

> events.js:167 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead
>   (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) Emitted 'error' event at: at
>   emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8) at emitErrorAndCloseNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)

But when run in Local Machine, its working fine. the error occurs only when run in remote Linux Machine.

somebody can help me how I can fix that problem?

Comment: Seems like file is missing or you don't have the permission to read the file.

Comment: it is working fine initially, but getting error only after 3 to 5 hours.

Comment: Hi @Shabhana, how you fix this issue at the end, do you still remember it? I am facing the same error now, and I am also working under my local is fine, but under my office network the error occurs. I am thinking this is related to the proxy setting, but i could not found out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use fs.watchFile once , because fs.watch is not consistent across platforms,

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

Change your code according to the requirement.

Comment: it is working fine initially, but getting error only after 3 to 5 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It has been happening since the users are closing the browser before the data request is received, leading to Connection Reset.

Used PM2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run the application, and it is working great now .

Comment: could you elaborate on how did PM2 solve the issue. Was it the issue with Node server or the target server where you are trying to read the file from?